# XML-ize the list of UI-controls on a HTML5 page

Tags: javascript, xml, html, uicontrolevents

I have started using Javascript and HTML5 from last week and quite new to it.
Maybe whatever I am asking is quite easy to do but googling around is not helping me. 
I want to loop thru ALL of the UI-controls on a HTML5 page (maybe using a javascript function or alike) and seek the specific details of each UI-control (like name, width, length and other properties) and write these details into a pre-determined xml-format. My backend code is in C# but I dont think that would matter or help as all of the related elements like UI-page-controls are in HTML5 and Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the Controls property of your Page.  Html5 does not (necessarily) conform to XML standards.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt340bh4(v=vs.100).aspx should show you a few good examples of working with Controls on the backend.

Comment: Thanks  Traxxus for your answer... but if I am understanding it rght, I am trying to do this for HTML5 based library of UI-controls where as the example-link you have given stands true for *.aspx page based controls.